# ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm getting this error when trying to launch my project, I think there is a mismatch in the architecture of the mysql with the python version? However I can't point out what exactly is wrong, and how to fix it.

Thank you

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python MySQL wrong architecture error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061277/python-mysql-wrong-architecture-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PyCharm, make sure to point to the correct path for MySQL. If it's running in the console but not in PyCharm; check the Environment Variables. On the top navigation, next to the green arrow, click on the arrow pointing down / Edit configuration then in Env variables add the path to mysql. In my case:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ||| /usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

For the Mac users with similar issues, this tutorial is great:
http://gpiot.com/mac-os-x-lion-the-perfect-setup-for-python-django/