# MySQLdb Issue with Python 2.7.6 on Yosemite

Tags: python, mysql, osx-yosemite

I'm needing to connect to a MySQL database that is on my local machine via a Python script. Here's my setup:

- Installed (and have been using for developing web apps for several months) MySQL 5.6.22 (downloaded .dmg from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/))
- Running the pre-installed python (2.7) that came with Yosemite
- Downloaded: `MySQL-python-1.2.4b4.tar.gz` and installed via terminal by running `python setup.py install` in the unzipped folder

This is the output I got at the end of the installation:

```
Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for distribute==0.6.28`
Finished processing dependencies for distribute==0.6.28
Processing MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg
Extracting MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Adding MySQL-python 1.2.4b4 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.4b4
Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.4b4
```

But when trying to connect, my py script gives me this error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/_mysql.so
Reason: image not found
('result', 256)
```

When I do

```
$ python
>>> import MySQLdb
```

I get the same error.

Any ideas on how I might get this sorted out?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599830/installing-mysql-python-on-mac

Comment: @thavan I've got Developer tools installed and pip refuses to install, it gives me this error everytime: `Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/pip/`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure you have `libmysqlclient.18.dylib`. On my mac, it's path is: `/opt/local/lib/mysql56/mysql/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`. If you don't have, you may need to get it by installing mysql5-devel.

If you have the dynamic library, the reason is that _mysql.so's information is wrong. You can use `otool` command to check it.

```
otool -L /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/_mysql.so
```

It will show that the path this command tells you is not the correct path of the dynamic library. You can use the following command to fix it.

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib {this is the correct path for mysql dynamic library} /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/_mysql.so
```