# Connect mysql to django

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I would to connect Django (1.10) from my localhost (MacOS X) to a Mysql Database (Mysql-server) which is located on a distant server (Ubuntu 14.04) instead of sqlLite3.

I made some changes in the Django' settings.py file :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Etat_Civil',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '172.**.**.58',
        'PORT': '80',
    }
```

On the distant server, I installed `mysql-server` and I juste created a table.

And when I run :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get this error :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Valentin:Etat_Civil valentinjungbluth$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I need to install another thing in order to connect Django (Python) to MySQL ? Or I have to change :

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

by

```
'ENGINE': 'mysql-server',
```

---

If I run :

```
python3.5 manage.py migrate
```

I get :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Valentin:Etat_Civil valentinjungbluth$ python3.5 manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Thank you for help :)

EDIT AFTER SOME STEPS :

Nothing for the moment. I followed your advices and this tutorial and none result for the moment : [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Do you have a virtual env setup that you forgot to activate ? Also, if you have a requirements file, make sure you run it.

Comment: Few questions: 1) are you sure about the port 80 on mysql server? default is not 80 2) In past I have had to install MySQL-python, can you check with `pip freeze` if that is installed?

Comment: @karthikr I forgot the virtual.env. So I followed a tutorial, now it's activated, but I get always this error `Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'`

Comment: @Aditya I'm not sure fort the port. Where I can see the port ? In mysql config ? For `pip freeze` I don't have something like `MySQL-Python`

Comment: Are you sure that your `MySQL` is running on port `80`? As default port for MySQL is `3306`

Comment: @Andromedae93 try twp steps: 1) try setting `mysql port to 3306` -> see if it works, if not 2) `pip install MySQL-python`

Answer (score 1):

You can find your ans here [Database configuration](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Database configuration snippet from the link

> Configure the Django Database Settings:
>
> Now that we have a project, we need to configure it to use the
>   database we created.
>
> Open the main Django project settings file located within the child
>   project directory:
>
> ```
> nano ~/myproject/myproject/settings.py
> ```
>
> Towards the bottom of the file, you will see a DATABASES section that
>   looks like this:
>
> ```
> . . .
>
> DATABASES = {
>     'default': {
>         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
>         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
>     }
> }
>
> . . .
> ```
>
> This is currently configured to use SQLite as a database. We need to
>   change this so that our MySQL/MariaDB database is used instead.
>
> First, change the engine so that it points to the mysql backend
>   instead of the sqlite3 backend. For the NAME, use the name of your
>   database (myproject in our example). We also need to add login
>   credentials. We need the username, password, and host to connect to.
>   We'll add and leave blank the port option so that the default is
>   selected:
>
> ```
> . . .
>
> DATABASES = {
>     'default': {
>         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
>         'NAME': 'myproject',
>         'USER': 'myprojectuser',
>         'PASSWORD': 'password',
>         'HOST': 'localhost',
>         'PORT': '',
>     }
> }
>
> . . .
> ```
>
> When you are finished, save and close the file.

Answer (score 0):

the last line states `Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?` 
.. so, did you?

If it really is mysql related,
make sure to install some modules:

```
$ pip install mysqlclient    # python 2 and 3
$ pip install MySQL-python   # python 2
$ pip install pymysql        # python 2 and 3
```

Comment: Each time I'm using pip, I get this error : `EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found. Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python`

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599830/installing-mysql-python-on-mac) helps. Basically, you need some help from `brew`. 
I have had the same error on mac the the steps in above question helped

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I finally did it: First I installed the command line developer tools required by running the following code inside the virtualenv

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

Then I installed MySQL-python by using the following code

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Finally I migrated the database using:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It worked without any errors The main problem with the error was that I didn't installed the command line developer tools required.