# 【Django×Google App Engine】No module named 'MySQLdb'　when deploying

Tags: django, google-app-engine, dialogflow-es

I'm setting GitHub source ↓

https://github.com/priyankavergadia/Django-Dialogflow-GoogleVisionAPI

But I have trouble in [Deploy the app to the App Engine standard environment] phase.
At a glance Deploying have been done well.But I'm trying to access webservice, so [502 Bad Gateway] appears.

- At local environment(running python manage.py runserver), this program works well.

Please give me some advices.

My environment:

- Windows10
- Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
- django 2.2.4
- MySQL second generation 5.7
- mysql django

I serched and tried to:

1. install mysqlclient and uninstall PyMySQL
2. rewrite [import ～]part in various pattern...

description in Django setting.py below

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

# Install PyMySQL as mysqlclient/MySQLdb to use Django's mysqlclient adapter
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers
# for more information
import MySQLdb as sql# noqa: 402

# [START db_setup]
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/michatbot-250809:us-central1:polls-instance2',
            'USER': 'test',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'NAME': 'polls',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:

    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'NAME': 'polls',
            'USER': 'test',
            'PASSWORD': '',
        }
    }
# [END db_setup]
```

eroor log on Google App Engine below

```
   textPayload: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 104, in init_process
    super(ThreadWorker, self).init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/srv/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mysite.wsgi import application
  File "/srv/mysite/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/srv/mysite/settings.py", line 82, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as sql  # noqa: 402
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two threads where the community figured out several ways to solve this error depending on your SO and software's versions. You can refer to these [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb), [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024891/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysqldb), and also to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-in-python-3-on-windows) that addresses discussion more about connecting MySQL in Python 3 on Windows.

Make sure to follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart) about Python 3.7 in the GAE Standard. Also, GAE has some specific support for using Django, I'd suggest going through the Django Support [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) and [Django App example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-django-skeleton).

Comment: It`s kind of you to reply me. I think that i can't solve this probrem now. i will read documentations you told me and challenge again. Thanks!