# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I created a virtualenv  with following installed:

```
$ pip freeze
aniso8601==9.0.1
attrs==22.2.0
click==8.1.3
configparser==5.3.0
Flask==2.2.2
flask-restplus==0.13.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.2
greenlet==2.0.1
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
jsonschema==4.17.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
mysql-connector-python==8.0.31
protobuf==3.20.1
PyMySQL==1.0.2
pyrsistent==0.19.2
pytz==2022.7
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.45
Werkzeug==2.2.2
```

You can see I have PyMySQL and mysql-connector-python installed but still I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ciasto/Dev/crud_app/src/start.py", line 1, in <module>
    from todo_app.extensions import db
  File "/home/ciasto/Dev/crud_app/src/todo_app/extensions.py", line 5, in <module>
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
  File "/home/ciasto/Dev/crud_app/crud_app_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 219, in __init__
    self.init_app(app)
  File "/home/ciasto/Dev/crud_app/crud_app_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 320, in init_app
    engines[key] = self._make_engine(key, options, app)
  File "/home/ciasto/Dev/crud_app/crud_app_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 606, in _make_engine
    return sa.engine_from_config(options, prefix="")
  File "/home/ciasto/Dev/crud_app/crud_app_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 743, in engine_from_config
    return create_engine(url, **options)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/home/ciasto/Dev/crud_app/crud_app_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 309, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ciasto/Dev/crud_app/crud_app_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 548, in create_engine
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/home/ciasto/Dev/crud_app/crud_app_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 163, in dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I have tried reinstalling
pip install MySQL-python
pip install ConfigParser
pip install MySQLdb

I have tried the solutions from the [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024891/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysqldb)

but it didn't worked for me.
I am using ubuntu jammy on x86 platform.

Comment: Can you post your code? Also, do you mean to `import pymysql`? Docs: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/#example

Comment: Could you show us the DATABASE_URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by first installing

```
apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

then `pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you're missing mysql connector package.

install mysql connector package

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Edit your Database URL

```
SQLALCHEMY_URL = "mysql+mysqlconnector://your_username:your_password@localhost/your_database"
```