# SQLAlchemy is not connecting with flask app

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, libmysqlclient

When I connect my SQLAlchemy to flask app, it gives me the following error

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 152, in import_dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Comment: Did you installed the MySQLdb package in the environment where you are running your app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024891/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysqldb)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `pip install MySQL-python`.  Here are the docs for it [PyPi MySQL Docs](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/).  Make sure this package supports your system architecture and that your version of python supports this package.