# Macports and virtualenv site-packages Fallback

Tags: python, django, macos, virtualenv, macports

I've installed django and python as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904039/django-mysql-on-mac-os-10-6-2-snow-leopard) suggested with macports. However, I'd like to use virtualenv to install more packages.  My understanding is that if I **do not** pass in the `--no-site-packages` to `virtualenv`, I should get the currently installed packages in addition to whatever packages I install into the virtual environment. Is this correct?

As an example, I've installed django through macports and then create a virtual environment, but I cannot import django from within that virtual environment:

```
[streeter@mordecai]:~$ mkvirtualenv django-test
New python executable in django-test/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
...
(django-test)[streeter@mordecai]:~$ pip install django-debug-toolbar
Downloading/unpacking django-debug-toolbar
  Downloading django-debug-toolbar-0.8.4.tar.gz (80Kb): 80Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-debug-toolbar
Installing collected packages: django-debug-toolbar
  Running setup.py install for django-debug-toolbar
Successfully installed django-debug-toolbar
Cleaning up...
(django-test)[streeter@mordecai]:~$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
>>>
```

So I can install packages into the virtual environment, but it isn't picking up the global site-packages. Or am I not doing something correctly / missing something / misunderstanding how `virtualenv` works?

I've got Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard), have updated my macports packages and am using macports' python26 (via `python_select python26`).

**Edit:**

Also I've checked that my macports PATH is setup correctly. Here's some output:

```
[streeter@mordecai]:~$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
[streeter@mordecai]:~$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/streeter/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/streeter/.ec2/bin
[streeter@mordecai]:~$ source dev/python-environments/test/bin/activate
(test)[streeter@mordecai]:~$ python --version
Python 2.6.1
(test)[streeter@mordecai]:~$
```

`virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` were both installed using `pip`, not using macports as that didn't seem to create a file to source at `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`, so I'm not sure how to get the aliases for virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: Have you tried: `mkvirtualenv django-test --python=/path/to/macports/python`?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the MacPorts Python as evidenced by the version and date displayed.  (Try typing `/usr/bin/python2.6` and then `/opt/local/bin/python2.6`.)  Just setting MacPorts `python_select` does no good if you do not put the MacPorts `bin` directory first on your shell execution `PATH`:

```
$ export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

You may need to recreate the `virtualenv` making sure you are using the MacPorts Python instead of the Apple-supplied Python.

EDIT: With the additional information, I would guess that your $PATH was not set properly prior to *initially* sourcing `virtualwrapper.sh` as described [here](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/install.html#python-interpreter-and-path).  I suggest you go back and follow the instructions there, making sure you have really installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` to the MacPorts site-packages directory, and not the system Python's.  Note, the version of `virtualenvwrapper` currently available through MacPorts for Python 2.6 is an older one, 1.20;  the shell script for it has [a different name](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/install.html#upgrading-from-1-x).