# MySQLdb error when running python server on MacOSX10.6

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

Running my server (python manage.py runserver) yielded this error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

I attempted the winning solution on this page with no avail: [Django + MySQL on Mac OS 10.6.2 Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904039/django-mysql-on-mac-os-10-6-2-snow-leopard)

And then moved on to try Thierry Lam (5 votes) on [Django - MySQLdb: Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299013/problem-using-mysqldb-symbol-not-found-mysql-affected-rows)

After Thierry Lam's suggestions, my error now reads:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/steven/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Which seems very much like the same linking issue. Any wisdom to share? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you have everything installed right, but it can't find libmysqlclient.  Have you tried the following?

```
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Your first line solved my problem - what exactly does this do? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: You are creating a symbolic link.  Your python-mysql module expects it to be in a different place than where it was installed.  Now when it looks for the library the symbolic link points it to the correct location.

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks. However, if I wanted to remove the symbolic link how would i do this? What exactly does a symbolic link do?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your just missing the mysql-python dependancy for mysql and Django.
Don't know how you installed Django though. Use pip or easy_install to install it.

```
pip install mysql-python
```

For Django it is recommended to use PostgreSQL though, for development purposes setting up a sqlite database is much, much easier.