# Something wrong with Mysqldb for python on mac

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Hi I'm trying to install mysqldb for python on a mac and below is the trace. Can anyone help?

```
>>> import MySQLdb
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/_mysql.py:3: UserWarning: Module _mysql was already imported from /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/_mysql.pyc, but /Users/christopherfarm/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.3 is being added to sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/christopherfarm/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/christopherfarm/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here. Not exactly sure what the symbolic link does though and if there are any better alternative solutions.

[MySQLdb error when running python server on MacOSX10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414407/mysqldb-error-when-running-python-server-on-macosx10-6)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```