# django MySQLdb not syncing

Tags: python, mysql, django

Running syncdb, following tutorial at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srHZoj3ASmk
Not sure what this error means and googling it seems to not produce anything useful.

```
lm-afrieden-2:PythonGraphNavigator afrieden$ ./manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in  execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
  klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
  module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
  __import__(name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
  from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 6, in <module>
  from django.db import models
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
  return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
  backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
  return import_module('.base', backend_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
  __import__(name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
  raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so
Reason: image not found
```

Thanks!

Comment: same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib   You need to create a symbolic link to libmysqlclient.18.dylib in /usr/lib

Comment: [This][1] post might be what you're looking for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module … Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

The error is pretty clear: you've got problems with mysql client library. Try reinstalling it.