# import MySQLdb ImportError

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, ssh

I think I installed MySQL correctly. Almost positive, except for the fact that it isn't working

```
$ python
>>> import MySQLdb
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/msmith/Documents/dj/mysite/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/msmith/Documents/dj/mysite/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a symbolic link to the library

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

or add this path to your profile

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.15-osx10.6-x86/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this could be a duplicated question. You can find the way to install or link the library file in this post [Python mysqldb: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib)