# Python import MySQLdb: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-python

macOS Sierra 10.12.1

MySQL 5.7.16

MySQL-python 1.2.5

Python 2.7

=======================================

When i

```
    import MySQLdb
```

it show errors as follow

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/aldirc/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/aldirc/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
      Reason: image not found
```

I have tried refered to [Python mysqldb: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib) like

```
    $ sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib  /usr/local/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib  /Users/aldirc/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.5/build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.so
```

also

```
    $ sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib  /usr/local/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib  /Users/aldirc/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
```

also

```
    $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

but they all don't work!

Now how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use package like pymysql or sqlalchemy instead

**Using pymysql**

```
import pymysql.cursors
mysql_connection = pymysql.connect(host=hostname,
                         user=username,
                         password=password,
                         db=database,
                         charset='utf8mb4',
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

**Using SqlAlchemy**

```
import sqlalchemy 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

sql_connection = 'mysql+mysqldb://'+str(user)+':'+str(password)+'@'+str(host)+'/'+str(database)+'?charset=utf8mb4'
mysql_connection = create_engine(sql_connection, echo=False, pool_recycle = 3600,pool_size=1000)
```