# get error when import deepchem

Tags: python, anaconda

I used anaconda4.2.0+python3.5.3 environment.

And install deepchem in a new conda environment using the conda commands in scripts/install_deepchem_conda.sh.

however when I run.

```
import deepchem as dp.
```

the error pops up.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Jackie/anaconda/envs/deepchem/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rdkit/Chem/rdmolops.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXrender.1.dylib
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: It has a simple solution. You can use the link below. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib][1]