# Getting "Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib", "Reason: image not found" with flask_mysqldb

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, mysql-python, flask-mysql

I'm trying out Python 3 with Flask and I'm stuck with the following error while working with databases.

*I'm doing this on macOS High Sierra v. 10.13.6*

**My import code is as follows:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, request, logging
from data import Articles
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordFeild, validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
```

**The error I get when trying to run the app, is the following:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
        from flask_mysqldb import MySQL  
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
          packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 1, in <module> import MySQLdb  
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
          packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module> import _mysql  
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
             packages/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: 
             libssl.1.0.0.dylib  
    Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
                     packages/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so  
    Reason: image not found
```

I've looked around in multiple other questions related to mine, but couldn't seem to find anything to solve my problem with. Or at least I didn't know how.
I really hope someone can help me out.

Comment: brew install mysql ?

Comment: Already done, same error :/

Comment: `pip install mysql`.  @M.Quist hope it works

Comment: @jalazbe that gives me the following error:
`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-juotsd7s/MySQL-python/` in the terminal

Comment: have you installed mysql on your computer?

Comment: @jalazbe
I have indeed

Comment: try doing `pip install flask_mysqldb`. Then open a new terminal. Type `python`, then type `import flask_mysqldb`. If no errors are prompted you should be ok

Comment: Bad I know but you can also do `sudo pip install mysql` followed by `python -c 'import flask_mysqldb'` - no output means you are good to go.

Comment: @jalazbe Having tried that already by reading other questions, I can say that it gives me the error written in my question once again

Comment: Also try (sudo) `pip install --upgrade setuptools` before you do pip install mysql

Comment: @jtlz2 Installing mysql with pip/pip3 gives me the error in comment three

Comment: Read this. It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib

Comment: Can you try it with `sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools; sudo pip install mysql` first?

Comment: @jtlz2 Gives my this error when running:  

`Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-cUPsLz/MySQL-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-E8aY4Y/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-cUPsLz/MySQL-python/`

Comment: I'm so sorry - going to keep quiet now..

Comment: @jtlz2 No worries, thanks for helping out!

Comment: Except possibly: Try link/unlink mysql with brew

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Solved the Issue**

After doing some more search I found a fix that worked for me:

*Step 1: Install openssl using brew*

> `brew install openssl`

*Step 2: Copy libssl.1.0.0.dylib and libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib*

> `cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1f/lib`
>   `sudo cp libssl.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/`

*Note the folder name (1.0.1f). There will be change in that depending on your openssl version*

*Step 3: Remove the existing links*

> `sudo rm libssl.dylib libcrypto.dylib`
>   `sudo ln -s libssl.1.0.0.dylib libssl.dylib`
>   `sudo ln -s libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.dylib`

*That's it.*

Answer (score 6):

Following worked for me with mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for osx10.14 (x86_64)
& Django 2.2.3.

1. Install version 1.1

```
   brew install openssl@1.1
```

2. Copy required library to /usr/lib location. Refer to article at this url if you have trouble copying to /usr/lib location. [System Integrity Change](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x)

```
    cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1c/lib
    sudo cp libssl.1.1.dylib libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/lib/
```

3. Remove and update link

```
    sudo rm libssl.dylib libcrypto.dylib
    sudo ln -s libcrypto.1.1.dylib libcrypto.dylib
    sudo ln -s libssl.1.1.dylib libssl.dylib
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! This was the one that did it for me. I had to disable the Mac's SIP in order to copy the files to /usr/lib. Perhaps there could have been a non SIP directory that it could have been copied without going into recovery mode

Comment: You can also get around this problem without disabling MacOS SIP by simply copying the files to `/usr/local/lib`.  That worked for me.

Comment: Not a good idea to copy those files into /usr/lib: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238828/root-user-cant-create-a-file-in-usr-lib

Comment: It says "Operation not permitted." for `sudo cp libssl.1.1.dylib libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/lib/`

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I was getting the following error.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

for the following import

```
import gdal
```

Just create the directory in the desired location

My installation was here...

> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/

I created a directory at their desired location. openssl directory was not there, I mkdir ed it.

> /usr/local/opt/openssl/

Then copied the folder as required. Now

```
import gdal
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem was this:

Instead of:

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

I used:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

So this means that I `pip install flask-mysql` instead of `pip install flask-mysqldb`. 
Note: if you want to obtain a cursor, with this lib you can do `cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()`

Answer (score 0):

In case of Mac, in the `~/.bash_profile` where you are updating the openssl path. Escape the `openssl@1.1` as `openssl\@1.1`.

`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl\@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl\@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl\@1.1/include"`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I already had openssl installed and the solution was a simple one -- re-installing openssl:

```
brew reinstall openssl@1.1
```

After that, the imports in python worked smoothly.