# Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib. Reason: image not found

Tags: python, macos, mysql-python, flask-mysql

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details about this error. Tell us what have you tried to do? If you have codes paste it into your question. Unless we can't help you

Comment: @Kalana i uploaded a picture of the error. I am just trying to make an import MySQL from flask_mysqldb.

Comment: Did you just upgrade to Python3.8 from an older Python version?

Comment: @GinoMempin Yes i did

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 flask-mysqldb: Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966962/python3-flask-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib)