# Pycurl is installed on my computer, but is not being recognised or found in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pycurl

i have been writing a script in python in the IDE PyCharm , but pycurl is not being imported. This is the error which I recieve:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/danielraad/PycharmProjects/VisualiseGrocery/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycurl.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/danielraad/PycharmProjects/VisualiseGrocery/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycurl.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

despite the fact that pip install pycurl returns Requirement already satisfied. I've tried to import it using the project interpreter through systems preferences but this hasnt changed anything.

I am running Python version 3.7

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib", "Reason: image not found" with flask\_mysqldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966962/getting-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib-reason-image-not-found-with)

Comment: Are you sure the environment where you pip installed pycurl is the same used in pycharm for your project? Having the wrong interpreter selected for your project in pycharm is often the reason of such problems.