# macOS (BigSur) - Installing MySQL ODBC driver for connecting a mysql db to Tableau

Tags: mysql, macos, odbc, tableau-desktop, iodbc

I want to install the mysql driver in macOS for connecting the mysql db with Tableau, while I downloaded the .dmg file for this driver and as a dependency I downloaded the iODBC administrator also.

After that I am following this site - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-macos.html

at the step for installation -

**myodbc-installer -a -d -n "MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver" -t "Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc8w.so"**

it throws up an error and print this -

arpitnigam@Arpits-MacBook-Pro ~ % myodbc-installer -a -d -n "MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver" -t "Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc8w.so"
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.1.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/myodbc-installer
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/bin/../lib/libssl.1.1.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/bin/../lib/libssl.1.1.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: library load disallowed by system policy
/usr/local/bin/../lib/libssl.1.1.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
/usr/local/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: library load disallowed by system policy
zsh: abort      myodbc-installer -a -d -n "MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver" -t

In short the code signature for this libssl.1.1.dylib is not recognized by the system as it says.

I have downloaded this driver from - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

**Please help me find the solution.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your error, but after doing some research, people seem to have success solving similar issues by using `openssl`. This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966962/getting-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib-reason-image-not-found-with) seems like a pretty good place to start.

That being said, I also found this recent [post](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-code-4d78f526-connecting-to-postgres-from-a-mac?lang=ko-kr) in the Tableau forum. Might be that there is an underlying problem with Tableau-DB connections on MacOS.

Comment: It's okay as now I am syncing mysql db to snowflake and then taking snowflake's data to tableau for visualising it.