# Getting django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module, while trying to perform the first migration

Tags: mysql, django

I am setting up a Django backend for my application. I am trying to change the default sqlite database to mysql. While performing the **first** migration, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py",
>   line 15, in 
>       import MySQLdb as Database   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       import _mysql ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
>   Reason: image not found
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 15, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 357, in execute
>       django.setup()   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/**init**.py",
>   line 24, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
>   line 112, in populate
>       app_config.import_models()   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
>   line 198, in import_models
>       self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 678, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager   File
>   "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 101, in **new**
>       new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 305, in add_to_class
>       value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py",
>   line 203, in contribute_to_class
>       self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())   File
>   "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/**init**.py",
>   line 33, in **getattr**
>       return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
>   line 202, in **getitem**
>       backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
>   line 110, in load_backend
>       return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "/Users/user1/djangoApp/djangoProject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       ) from err django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.

- OS:macOS Mojave
- Framework: Django
- I am using a virtualenv

I have already installed "mysqlclient" using the command

> pip3 install mysqlclient

I have verified that the mysqlclient folder exists under the installed location.

I have the mysql server up and running.

I have tried many available solutions online but nothing works

**To reproduce:**

1 - Start a django project using

> "django-admin startproject djangoApp"

2 - Install and start the mysql server.

3 - Update the settings.py file of the entry application to the     following

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangoApp',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```

4 - Now try to migrate using

> python manage.py migrate

**Expected**:The migration should be successful

**Actual**:Migration fails with the given error

**I am new to Django**

Comment: P.S. djangoApp is name of my django project as well as my database

Comment: have you run  "python manage.py makemigrations" ?

Comment: The traceback is showing that you did not install Django in a virtualenv. Where is the virtualenv, how did you activate it, and was it activated when you installed both Django and mysqlclient?

Comment: @Mohit Harshan I am not able to run that command either

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for pointing that out. I posted the incorrect traceback. I activated it using the command "source env/bin/activate "I  get the same traceback when I run the command in my virtualenv.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Updated the Traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to symlink the lib files to the /usr/local/lib directory.

[Fourth answer in the link worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib)

Thank you @Mohit Harshan @Daniel Rosema for taking time out to help me