# Unable to import MySQLdb in python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, homebrew, mysql-python

So I am working on a python project which needs MySQL. I work on macOS Mojave.
For this earlier I had installed MySQL using homebrew:

```sh
brew install mysql@5.7
```

However, later I realised I need MySQL 5.6. So I did the following:

```sh
brew remove mysql@5.7
brew install mysql@5.6
```

Now when I open **python 2.7**, and import `MySQLdb`, I get the following error:

```py
import MySQLdb
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/97amarnathk/miniconda3/envs/py27_dirac/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/97amarnathk/miniconda3/envs/py27_dirac/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/97amarnathk/miniconda3/envs/py27_dirac/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

It is looking for MySQL 5.7 but I have installed MySQL 5.6.

So how do I make the system use MySQL 5.6?

Comment: can you please post the output for `pip list | grep -i mysql`. That should help to diagnose the issue with more clarity. Also, do try reinstalling `MySQL-python`, maybe it's still linking with the old version of mysql objects.

Comment: @pikaynu `MySQL-python                       1.2.5` is the output

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib

Comment: I tried but it was of no help.